# when I load saved model, KeyError: 'query_shape' are occured in keras

Tags: python, keras, multihead-attention

I followed this [timeseries classification Transformer model example](https://keras.io/examples/timeseries/timeseries_transformer_classification/) in keras.

When I trained, and valided in one file, It works well.

But, when I saved that model, and import model to test file using

```
loadModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(baseModelPath+modelName)
```

occured error.

error shown like that...

```
---> 50         loadModel = tf.keras.models.load_model(baseModelPath+modelName)
```

and follows some other modules... and last error is

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/keras/layers/attention/multi_head_attention.py in from_config(cls, config)
    307         # If the layer has a different build() function from the Keras default,
    308         # we need to trigger the customized build to create weights.
--> 309         query_shape = config.pop("query_shape")
    310         key_shape = config.pop("key_shape")
    311         value_shape = config.pop("value_shape")

    KeyError: 'query_shape'
```

why this problem occured? If saved module is problem, then train code is problem. So, I think if module is problem, then train isn't work correctly. But, train and validation are  really works well. So I really don't know what's the problem in this case.

I'm using google colab. Thanks for helping.

Comment: I solved that problem. First, use the newest Tensorflow(>=2.12). And retrained the model. It works well. I can't answering at my question, so I wrote solution here.